# Do multiple encounters combine for craft?

Tags: talisman

On page ten of the rulebook, there is the rule:

> If there is more than one Enemy that attacks by Strength on a space and they have the same encounter number, they fight as one during battle, adding their Strength together with just one attack roll to make a single, combined stack score.

Does this rule still apply if a player encounters two or more enemies that attack by Craft? What if one enemy attacks by Strength, but the other attacks by Craft?

Comment: You should specify which edition of Talisman you are asking about.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am assuming 4th edition (Fantasy Flight Games) here.

For the two cases you laid out:

- If there are two Craft enemies on the same space, then according to the rules as written, their craft scores would be combined. The rules for Psychic Combat (combat using Craft) are literally Ctrl-C Ctrl-V the rules for Battles (combat using Strength), and then find-replace "Strength" with "Craft". So, yes, that rule does apply for encountering two enemies that attack with Craft.
- If a Craft enemy and a Strength enemy are on the same space, both enemies are fought separately (one in Battle, one in Psychic Combat). The lower encounter number is fought first, then the other.

Comment: For reference, the exact text from the 4e rules, page 12, is: "Psychic combat is resolved in exactly the same manner as battles (see “Battles” on page 10), except: 1. Craft is substituted for Strength. 2. No Object can prevent the loss of a life."

Comment: Your interpretation also matches the way that the official Talisman app behaves, so I presume that it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

This rule only applies for Strength, unless there is some errata they choose not to print. I hope this help!